# List comprehension is removing first character, why?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement a function that eliminates the spaces of a string. I don't understand why this list comprehension is eliminating the first character, if the predicate explicitly filters only empty spaces.

```
import Data.List
import System.IO

noSpace :: String -> String
noSpace (x:xs) = [x | x <- xs, x /= ' ']

main = do
  print(noSpace("8 j 8   mBliB8g  imjB8B8  jl  B"))
```

Result:

```
"j8mBliB8gimjB8B8jlB"
```

Should be:

```
8j8mBliB8gimjB8B8jlB
```

Answer (score 4):

The `x` in your pattern is not related to the `x` in your list comprehension; it's as if you wrote

```
noSpace (x:xs) = [y | y <- xs, y /= ' ']
```

Note that `x` is effectively dropped, because the list comprehension doesn't consider it.

You don't need both in this definition; the list comprehension is already capable of matching each character in the list on its own, so `noSpace` itself doesn't have to do any pattern matching.

```
noSpace xs = [x | x <- xs, x /= ' ']
```

This is just an alternate way of writing the `filter` function.

```
noSpace xs = filter (\x -> x /= ' ') xs
```

or simply

```
noSpace = filter (\x -> x /= ' ')
```

or even more simply

```
noSpace = filter (/= ' ')
```

Both simplifications come via [eta conversion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion).

Comment: list comprehensions are much more self-explanatory though. `filter p`? what's that do? is it filtering the `p` chars out, or in? with LC, no questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing the pattern match syntax.

```
noSpace (x:xs) = [x | x <- xs, x /= ' ']
--                this x has nothing to do with x in x:xs
--       this x is unused and dropped ftom the result
```

To fix:

```
noSpace xs = [x | x <- xs, x /= ' ']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are matching on `(x : xs)` (instead of just `(xs)`), so your function takes two parameters: the first element of the list and the rest. And then you only work on "the rest" (xs), and discard x altogether.

Probably you don't want to use a one-element tuple as a parameter, but this is another story.

Comment: One-element tuple? There is no such thing in Haskell, and I don't see what in the question what might make you think this. Also, while I think I see what you're trying to say, claiming this function takes two arguments is definitely incorrect.

Comment: @amalloy I never mentioned two arguments. When the lhs of a function definition introduces a variable, I think it is proper to call it "a parameter" - even if it is introduced by the pattern binding syntax (how else would I call it?). As for "what might make you think this" - the code calling the noSpace function wraps the string literal in parentheses, making it look like a one-element tuple. It's not an error (just an unnecessary grouping) but probably a misunderstanding which will blow up when OP calls a function with multiple arguments.